# my python program is to find prime numbers between two intervals but i am getting 9 in the output can you please tell what mistake i am doing

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, break

python code to give prime numbers between two intervals

```
start = int(input('enter starting point of interval:'))
end = int(input('enter ending point of interval:'))
for i in range(start,end+1):
    if i>1:
        for j in range(2,i+1):
            if (i % j == 0):
                break
            else:
                print(i, end = " ")
                break
```

the output if i put start and end as 2,10 was 3,5,7,9 please tell what mistake i am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of 9, you're checking if the number is divisible by 2, it's not, and then you print the number and don't check anything else.

You're also looping till `i+1`, meaning you check if the number is divisible by itself, which it is...

Try changing those:

```
start = int(input('enter starting point of interval:'))
end = int(input('enter ending point of interval:'))
for i in range(start,end+1):
    if i>1:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if (i % j == 0):
                break
        else:
            print(i, end = " ")
```

Also, instead of checking `if i>1` in every loop, change the loop conditions, and you can loop until the square root.

End result:

```
import math
start = int(input('enter starting point of interval:'))
end = int(input('enter ending point of interval:'))
for i in range(max(start, 2),end+1):
    if i % 2 == 0  and i != 2: continue
    if all((i%j!=0) for j in range(3,int(math.sqrt(i))+1, 2)):
        print(i, end = " ")
```